# How to delete a file from a databse using http java client

Tags: java, php

I'm trying to delete a file from phpMyAdmin database. I wrote a script in php that interacts with the database and deletes the specific file either by entering file id number for now(verifiied by using a web client). But now i want to delete with a http java client. But it isnt working. How do u delete a file using http java client. I downloaded the external jar file of apache. :

Here is my functions of my delete file using Jswing:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource()==button1)
    {
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to delete a file", "Delete File", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
          //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HELLO");
            String[] options = new String[]{"id","Filename"};
            int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Message", "Title",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null, options, options[0]);
            if(response == 0)
            {
                String userInput = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null,
                        "Enter the file name",
                        "Input",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
                CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
                String phpURL = "http://emysdomain.com/";
                JavaHttpClient.deleteFile(httpClient, userInput, phpURL);
                repaint();
                //String phpUrl is my domain name.
                //repaint to refresh the table. I think i'm wrong using repaint to refresh the table
            }
```

Here is my delete file of http java client:

```
 public static boolean deleteFile(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, String id, String uploadURL){
    HttpPost httppost      = null;
    HttpEntity resEntity   = null;
    HttpResponse response  = null;
    httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

    try {
        httppost = new HttpPost(uploadURL+"delete.php");  

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.addTextBody("id", id);
        httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());  
        response  = httpClient.execute(httppost);  

        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (resEntity != null)  
            EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);  

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();  
        if (statusCode <= HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT 
            && statusCode >= HttpStatus.SC_OK) //SC_OK = 200  
        {  
            return true;
        }  
    }  
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
        return false;
    }

    return false;
  }  
}
```

Below is my php delete file:

```
<?php
/**
 * 
 * 
 *
 * 
 */
  include 'db.php';
  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

  $file_name = $_POST["id"];
  if(isset($_POST["id"])){
  $id = $_POST["id"];
  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Files WHERE idFiles='$id'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $url = $row['url'];
  unlink($url);

  $query = "DELETE FROM Files WHERE idFiles='$id';";
  mysqli_query($con,$query);
 }

 mysqli_close($con);

 //redirect
 $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $uri  = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
 $extra = 'webclient.php';

 header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
 exit;
```

Comment: First of all, you are not deleting a file. You are deleting a row in a database table that happens to be named `Files`. Did you try to follow the example here? https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html Why don't you put some logs in the PHP script to see what you are receiving in the `$_POST` and also in the Java application to see what status code you are receiving. That would help us help you more!

Comment: What's in the `consume` method of `EntityUtils`?

Comment: @jbx thanks for the correction. Yes i meant to say am deleting a row.